# Sum a value based on a row and divide that value by column

Tags: php, database, sum

I need help for sum(values) base on rows.

so i have data like this

[image]

and i want sum based on rows so like this

[image]

after that i want to divide the data based on sum(rows)

so for no [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1w44.png)[harga] will be like this (results = 1 / 4.6),etc
maybe someone can help me?

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
       <tr>
          <th>No</th>
          <th>Alternatif</th>
             <?php
                $dd = $this->Mymod->ViewData('kriteria'); 
                foreach($dd as $i):
             ?>
          <th><?= $i['kriteria_nama']; ?></th>
             <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
             <?php
                $gc= $this->db->query("SELECT * from alternatif")->result_array();
                $dbobot=array();
                $no=0;
                foreach ($gc as $cc):
                $no++;
             ?>
          <tr>
          <td><?= $no; ?></td>
          <td><?= $cc['alternatif_nama']; ?></td>
             <?php
                $de= $this->db->query("SELECT * from nilai where alternatif_kode = '$cc[alternatif_kode]'")->result_array();
                foreach ($de as $cdd):
                $ef= $this->db->query("SELECT max(nilai_nilai) as maxNilaiK  from nilai where kriteria_kode = '$cdd[kriteria_kode]'")->row_array();
                $Mnormal = $cdd['nilai_nilai'] / $ef['maxNilaiK']
             ?>
          <td><?= $Mnormal; ?></td>
          <?php
          endforeach; ?>
          </tr>
          <?php 
          endforeach;
          ?>
    </table>
```

update : so based on my images i have table. on my table contain No, ALternatif, Harga, Kapasitas, Luas, Jenis, Fasilitas, Jarak. And every rows has data.

```
1. arrayGedungA ([1],   [0.25], [1],   [0.4], [0.25], [1]);
2. arrayGedungB ([0.4], [1],    [0.4], [1],   [1],    [0.8]);
3. arrayGedungC ([0.2], [1],    [0.4], [1],   [0.5],  [0.8]);
4. arrayGedungD ([0.4], [1],    [0.8], [1],   [1],    [0.4]);
5. arrayGedungE ([1],   [1],    [0.8], [0.2], [0.5],  [0.8]);
6. arrayGedungF ([0.8], [1],    [0.4], [1],   [0.5],  [0.8]);
7. arrayGedungG ([0.8], [0.5],  [0.4], [1],   [0.5],  [0.2]);
```

my questions is

1. i want to sum harga,kapasitas,luas,jenis,fasilitas, and jarak from top to bottom.

so data will be like this

```
Harga = (1 + 0.4 + 0.2 + 0.4 + 1 + 0.8 + 0.8) is 4.6
Kapasitas = (0.25 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 0.5) is 5.75
Luas = (1 + 0.4 + 0.4 + 0.8 + 0.8 + 0.4 + 0.4) is 4.2
Jenis = (0.4 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 0.2 + 1 + 1) is 5.6
Fasilitas = (0.25 + 1 + 0.5 + 1 + 0.5 + 0.5 + 0.5) is 4.25
Jarak = (1 + 0.8 + 0.8 + 0.4 + 0.8 + 0.8 + 0.2 ) is 4.8
```

after we have sum(rows) we need to divide them.
so will be like this

```
1. arrayGedungA ([1/4.6],   [0.25/5.75], [1/4.2],   [0.4/5.6], [0.25/4.25], [1/4.8]);
2. arrayGedungB ([0.4/4.6], [1/5.75],    [0.4/4.2], [1/5.6],   [1/4.25],    [0.8/4.8]);
3. arrayGedungC ([0.2/4.6], [1/5.75],    [0.4/4.2], [1/5.6],   [0.5/4.25],  [0.8/4.8]);
4. arrayGedungD ([0.4/4.6], [1/5.75],    [0.8/4.2], [1/5.6],   [1/4.25],    [0.4/4.8]);
5. arrayGedungE ([1/4.6],   [1/5.75],    [0.8/4.2], [0.2/5.6], [0.5/4.25],  [0.8/4.8]);
6. arrayGedungF ([0.8/4.6], [1/5.75],    [0.4/4.2], [1/5.6],   [0.5/4.25],  [0.8/4.8]);
7. arrayGedungG ([0.8/4.6], [0.5/5.75],  [0.4/4.2], [1/5.6],   [0.5/4.25],  [0.2/4.8]);
```

and results will be

[image: a]

Comment: Are you saying you want to do 1 divided by the column totals? Or are you strictly trying to sum?

Comment: i have harga, kapasitas, luas, etc. before divide, i want to sum total harga, kapasitas, luas, etc after that i want to divide them. ex. as you can see on harga we can se [1, 0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 1, 0.8, 0.8] and for total we have [4.6], so the results will be [0.2173, 0.0869, 0.0869, ..etc] . so  [1, 0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 1, 0.8, 0.8] / [4.6] = [0.2173, 0.0869, 0.0869, ..etc]

Comment: `so [1, 0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 1, 0.8, 0.8] / [4.6]` per your comment is 4.6/4.6 which is 1. I am trying to follow your problem but I cannot tell what math you need done.

Comment: What OP wants is a ratio of each value to the sum of the whole set, I presume.

Comment: Something like `SELECT harga/SUM(harga) FROM ...`

Comment: Just add `OVER()` after `SUM(...)` and it will still show you all rows but add another column with the value you want. This is called window function. i.e. `SELECT harga/SUM(harga) OVER() FROM ...`. But it depends on your DB whether it supports window functions.

Comment: @nerdlyist sorry for making you confused, now i have added a little explanation of what i am referring to.

Comment: @Dharman i think this is not about db maybe about php code? maybe multidimensi array

Comment: Then what is the problem, you have your pseudocode then code it. Although if you can do it when fetching the data would be better.

Comment: my problem is i cannot sum by row.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on database (and using the suggestion by Dharman) this works on Oracle:

```
SELECT harga,
       harga / SUM (harga) OVER () harga_sum,
       kapasitas,
       kapasitas / SUM (kapasitas) OVER () kapasitas_sum
  FROM nilai
 WHERE ...
```

Note that the OVER() has to be given after each SUM(...) and before aliased column names.

Comment: You haven't improved much upon my comment... I would suggest to add the optional `AS` to make the aliasing clearer.